# Amend a Git Commit from which another branch spawns

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Let's say I have commit `A`, on branch mainline, which is currently not pushed (e.g., because it's being code-reviewed).

In the meantime, I want to start working on a new feature `B`, based on commit `A`, so I create another branch and start working on it. This is the current situation:

```
--- A
     \
      -- B
```

In the meantime (e.g., because from the code review it has emerged I need to change something), I make some changes to commit `A`. I now want to amend commit A to include the new changes. What happens to commit `B`, at least in my head, is something like this:

```
   ----- A
  /
---- ?
      \
       ---- B
```

Where `?` is the old, not-yet-amended commit `A`, which now doesn't exist anymore. I assume this is not a good idea.

So what would be the correct way to do this?

I thought about not amending `A`, and instead create a new commit `A'`:

```
--- A ----- A'
     \
      -- B
```

Then, when I'm ready to push feature `A`, cherry-pick `A'` on `B` and then rebase `B` on `A'`:

```
--- A -- A'
          \
           -- B
```

Finally, squash `A` and `A'`, and push `A`.

This seems awfully convoluted and error-prone. Also, I'm not at all sure that it's the right way to go.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Amending a commit will replace `A` with `A'`. You can then rebase `B` onto `A'`.

Comment: That is, both situation aren't different at all, they're the same. :-)

Comment: "I assume this is not a good idea." Can you explain why you assume that? "This seems awfully convoluted and error-prone" It seems like ordinary post-production. You are proposing to change history. So change it.

Answer (score 2):

This is why I keep telling people that it is literally impossible to *change* a commit.

A commit is an entity that is denoted and found by its raw hash ID.  Your `A` and `B` above are just short, human-useful substitutions for the actual hash IDs, which are long and unweildy.

If you draw the graph out a bit further, it might look like:

```
...--H--A   <-- mainline
         \
          B   <-- another
```

When you go to "amend" commit `A` (presumably using `git commit --amend`), it's quite literally impossible to change it.  What you end up doing is making a new commit `A'` and *commit `A` still exists*, it's just that `mainline` no longer points to it, nor includes it in the set of commits reachable by starting from the tip and working backwards:

```
       A'  <-- mainline
      /
...--H--A
         \
          B   <-- another
```

The set of commits that is *unique to* `another`, or equivalently, the set of commits *reachable from* `another` but not from `mainline`, has grown, without anything in the commit graph itself changing.  That's because the set of commits *reachable from* `mainline` has changed because `mainline` itself has changed.

The *labels* move.  The commits do not!

Note that, like `git commit --amend`, `git rebase` also does not change any *existing* commits.  Instead, it (typically) *copies* commits, then moves the labels.  (The "typically" is here only because there are a few cases where rebase decides no work needs to be done and leaves existing commits in place.  You can force copies anyway, if there's some reason you want all-new commits with new hash IDs, but the default is to detect this situation and preserve as much as possible.)

Hence as [evolutionxbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982880/amend-a-git-commit-from-which-another-branch-spawns#comment96724046_54982880) and [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982880/amend-a-git-commit-from-which-another-branch-spawns#comment96724458_54982880) both said in comments, your situation is the same either way: having yanked the name `mainline` off commit `A`, you will want to copy commit `B` to some new `B'` whose parent is `A'`:

```
       A'  <-- mainline
      / \
...--H   B'   <-- another
      \
       A--B   [abandoned, but remembered for some time]
```

Eventually—typically some time 30 days or more in the future, after abandoning one or more commits like this—Git will *garbage collect* the unwanted commits.

The tricky part of using `git rebase` to copy `B` to `B'` is that if there are substantive differences in `A` vs `A'`, your Git will by default think that commit `A` should be copied *again*, producing—or trying to produce:

```
       A'  <-- mainline
      / \
...--H   A"-B'   <-- another
      \
       A--B   [abandoned, but remembered for some time]
```

(with, probably, a lot of merge conflicts between `A'` and `A"`).  There are multiple ways to go about preventing this, such as using `git rebase -i` or `git rebase --onto`.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to directly modify commit A which as you mentioned results in

```
   ----- A
  /
---- ?
      \
       ---- B
```

Then, while being at the branch of commit B you can remove commit ? by `git rebase -i B~2` and deleting the line corresponding to commit ?.

Finally, you can do `git rebase A` to get the final result.

Comment: This two-step process works only if `B` is independent from `A`. Otherwise, you can just `git rebase -i A` (the new `A`) and remove the line corresponding to commit ?.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how my recommened solution would fail if B and A were dependent?

Comment: Consider `?` added a new feature and `B` is using the new feature. Then after the first step, `B` is rebased onto the parent of `?`, but the feature that `B` depends on, is now not present anymore.